# Is it okay to not select an answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

There are a couple questions that I've asked that I don't really think have been answered correctly, or I don't really agree with the answer.

Is it ok that they go without me selecting one of them as correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, absolutely.**

However, it is probably wise to leave notes on existing answers as to what doesn't satisfy you. And if you one day learn the answer yourself, come back and answer your own question.